# check a php variable with a generic function that will work with any variable

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a PHP function that wraps around a variable that will check the variable value and change it if it matches another variable.
I'm sure I'm doing it wrong, but...

Here's what I have so far:

```
<?php 

function Clear_Value(){

    $val='NONE';

    if(this== $val){ this=='';}

    };

$one    = 'One';
$two    = 'Two';
$three  = 'NONE';
$four   = 'Four';

Clear_Value($one);
Clear_Value($two);
Clear_Value($three);
Clear_Value($four);

echo $one.'<br>';
echo $two.'<br>';
echo $three.'<br>';
echo $four.'<br>';

?>
```

The output I'm going for would be:

```
One
Two

Four
```

I hope that's clear. I'm still learning functions in php so any pointers would be great.

Thanks

Comment: You can only use `this` (which should be `$this`) within a class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass an argument by reference:

```
function Clear_Value(&$arg){

    if ($arg == 'NONE') $arg = '';
}
```

This way, the function can modify the variable's contents.

Live example: http://ideone.com/igHc5

Comment: This is a good approach (given current context) since this function can be used as a callback (i.e., array_map) instead of dealing with several variables.

Comment: That means you have two functions called `Clear_Value()` - remove your own one and just add this one.

Comment: Yeah, I did have two. Thanks! this is what I was after. So $arg could be anything, right? Also, what the PHP term for this so I can read up on it more?

Answer (score 1):

what your constant *this* stands for?

you have to create some input variable in your function and use *&* prefix (refers to variable in memory)

```
function Clear_Value(&$var){

 $val='NONE';

 if($var == $val) 
  $var = '';

};
```

and another thing, if you want to change value of a variable, you use just single "=". i recommend you to see basics of syntax at php.net

> *sorry for my english*

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you expect here.

But when you execute this program it will show undefined variable error.

Try my sample changed code:-

```
 <?php 

   function Clear_Value($sam){

   $val='NONE';

   if($sam== $val){ $sam=='';}
   echo $sam.'<br>';

   };

   $one    = 'One';
   $two    = 'Two';
   $three  = 'NONE';
   $four   = 'Four';

   Clear_Value($one);
   Clear_Value($two);
   Clear_Value($three);
   Clear_Value($four);
   /*
   echo $one.'<br>';
   echo $two.'<br>';
   echo $three.'<br>';
   echo $four.'<br>';
   */
   ?>
```